# Tweepi Imacros Help Please

Tags: twitter, imacros

I've been using Tweepi to try and record an iMacro to unfollow followers who do not follow me back, but have been unsuccessful so far. It just wouldn't work?

What i would do is press record, say no to close all tabs, then click each unfollow button..and after that i'll press next. However it still doesn't work.

Would appreciate it if someone could share a working Tweepi iMacro script to unfollow followers who do not follow you back.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tweepi has change the whole layout of the site in the last couple of months and its a bit harder to get imacros to work. So far, this is what I've got for "unfollowing":

```
var CODE="";
for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) 
    { 
        CODE="CODE:TAG POS=" + i + " TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:*label-light-default*ng-scope CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER \n";
        CODE=CODE + "TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow \n";
        iimPlay(CODE);
    }
```

The weird thing is, for some reason the "unfollow" action happens every 2 followers, so for every "unfollow" action, the next person to unfollow gets skipped and goes to the next one.
I'm still working on this so I'll keep you posted.
Cheers!